# How to get the accurate control in a repeater with Callback

Tags: c#, user-controls, callback

I've developed a page with postbacks but recently I decided to change it to use callbacks

> MasterPage
>
> > Page
> >
> > > Repeater
> > >
> > > > td1
> > > >
> > > > > literal to show description
> > > >
> > > > td2
> > > >
> > > > > EditControl*** (starts on view mode, on postback to edit mode with save button)

So I have 100 records and for each repeater item I have my control in view mode with the Edit button(linkbutton with href:javascript:void and the callback function Edit('',''))

When I click on Edit, it raise the callback event but at this point, imagine that I click on the 15th control in the repeater but the callback event thinks it's the first control in the repeater, I mean 1st row.

So how can I do to work the accurate control that I really click on it?

Because at the end, I return the control with HtmlTextWriter(RenderControl) and I send it to the client-side receiver data function to render it with innerHtml that works great but just with the first control in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a `CommandArgument` to the control so that when the event is raised, you can retrieve the args and know which button was clicked.

Your repeater needs an `ItemCommand` event:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_OnItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="repeater_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Inside the repeaters `ItemDataBound` event you would pass the link button a command argument:

```
protected void repeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        LinkButton lnkBtnEdit = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkBtnEdit");
        lnkBtnEdit.CommandArgument = "foo args";
    }
 }
```

Next in the `ItemCommand` event which is what will be raised when one of the link buttons is clicked, you get the Command Argument which tells you which linkbutton was clicked:

```
protected void repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
     //This is how you know which button was clicked
     string foo = e.CommandArgument;
}
```

In reality, you'd probably want to pass in the object ID of the item you're clicking, this would likely redirect to an edit page with the ID as a querystring param. In the edit page you would pull in data about that object by the ID.